# how to dynamically edit the bind data in sql using mvc3 web grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, binding, datagrid, edit

i am new to mvc.. i have a task that, i have to bind data from  existing table in sql using asp.net mvc3(Razor) Web Grid .. now i have to edit the data in webGrid.. i dont know how the edit operation is going to made... Plzz Help me out...

i have given my bind data.. plz let me know how to edit it...

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var list = GetList();
        return View(list); 
    }

    public List<Teacher> GetList()
    {
        var modelList = new List<Teacher>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=Demo;Data Source=CIPL41\SQLEXPRESS"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand dCmd = new SqlCommand("Select T_Id,T_Name,T_Address,Sub_Id from teacher", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(dCmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            conn.Close();
            for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                var model = new Teacher();
                model.T_Id = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["T_Id"]);
                model.T_Name = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["T_Name"].ToString();
                model.T_Address = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["T_Address"].ToString();
                model.Sub_Id = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Sub_Id"].ToString();
                modelList.Add(model);
            }
        }
        return modelList;
    }
    //
```

Index.cshtml

```
    @model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.Teacher>

    @{
      ViewBag.Title = "Index";
      }

    <h2>Index</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Teacher"))
       {

     <table>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>
        T_Id
    </th>
    <th>
        T_Name
    </th>
    <th>
        T_Address
    </th>
    <th>
        Sub_Id
    </th>

</tr>

 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {

<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.T_Id }) |
       @* @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.T_Id }) |*@
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {  id=item.T_Id })
    </td>
    <td>
       @Html.TextBox("T_Id",  item.T_Id , new { @style = "width:100px;" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBox("T_Name",  item.T_Name , new { @style = "width:100px;" }) 
        </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBox("T_Address",  item.T_Address , new { @style = "width:100px;" }) 
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBox("Sub_Id",item.Sub_Id,new { @style = "width:100px;"})
    </td>

</tr>
  }


  </table>
```

Plz help me out....

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view

I think it explains exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: thanks, but it was not exactly what i want. i want to edit the bind data from sql.. not a newly created table in the application.. where they uses DBContext and Dbset.  i wish u understand what i m trying to say..

Comment: Do you mean the part where they save it to the database? The HttpPost where they call db.SaveChanges()?